# Is it easy to get a permanent contract as a software engineer in Germany?

Tags: job-search, contracts, germany, entry-level

I'm a recent graduate looking for jobs as a software engineer and trying to understand the industry.

My question:

- Are permanent contracts easy to get? Say I spent 2 years at a company (with a limited contract), then they want me to stay for another project, then is it normally, in the German software industry, that I will get a permanent contract or should I negotiate for it?
- And what about entering a new company after 2 years of experience, is it easy to get a permanent contract from the very beginning? Or are there special conditions for it?

Comment: @Pepone a brief run through the questions most seem fine enough for workplace, this question seems the least fitting for workplace and I'd still put it on the positive side of grey, only because I think it doesn't have really a solid answer rather will likely be subjective/opinion based (Makes sense, guys got a lot of questions and technically we're supposed to have one question per post) And while this is an English site it's not an "Americans only" site. We've actually got a fairly large number of users from India here.

Comment: @RualStorge thanks. That's why I have the same stupid cliche introduction in all of my questions. To avoid having my questions marked "too broad".

Comment: @Pepone take care to read [this post](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2979/2322) and remember what comments are intended for. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Permanent employment is considered the standard way of employment in Germany.

If you are looking in online job portals, you will find more permanent than limited contract positions.

Getting a permanent contract should not be any harder than getting a temporary one.

Comment: Clear and to the point. The awesome German style. Thank you so much.

Comment: +1. It may well be harder to land a *limited* contract in Germany than a permanent one.

Comment: @StephanKolassa but this is strange. Why is that? I would assume the opposite!

Comment: @JackTwain I guess it's tradition. It is my impression that many Germans stick with their job for life, once they've found one they like. Btw, I'm a software developer in Germany and when I first started jobhunting 3 years ago, the Arbeitsamt told me there were 2 to 5 times as many open positions as applicants at that time, depending on region. And considering the trouble we have to get good applicants, it's probably still the case. So if you're a decent programmer, go get a job you'll like, with a permanent contract. There's no need to settle for less.

Comment: As @Sumyrda says. Germans, as a rule, place a high premium on stability. So on the one hand, if you are willing to settle for a non-permanent position, the prospective employer will wonder why that is and whether you will soon be gone. And conversely, the employer will usually want someone for the long haul, since that is what most applicants are interested in. It's really something of a chicken & egg problem, and a cultural thing.

Comment: @JackTwain Training people for a specific job takes time. Sometimes, developers reach their peak productive value after 3-6 months in a company. Having a developer looking for a new job after a year or two seems like a waste if you just trained him that long. So permanent positions make sense.

Comment: @LeonMeier I'm not sure I can follow. "Candidates per Position" is nothing companies take into account when deciding whether they look for a permanent position or not. In theory, they cannot even know that before offering the position (although obviously for many positions there are good estimations)

Answer (score 2):

Well, "easy" is a pretty subjective word.

That said, I am under the impression (myself working in Germany as well) that the market is quite good for the applicants.
There are many open positions.

Of course, your question is very general. The main factors playing a role are:

- Location : many positions in Berlin and Munich, a bit less in other places
- Exact field : Big data and Web/app programming are booming in Berlin,   Embedded software programming in Munich for example.

Now, about the "permanent" part of the contract, I believe it is standard.